# CUDA RuntimeError when moving a Tensor to a different device

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error

When I move a tensor to 'cuda', an erro occurs. And the situation is the same when I move a tensor from "cuda" to cpu.

I have checked my tensor`s shape and dtype, and everything is OK.
Does anyone know what the problem could be?

My Traceback:

```
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1678402411778/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1146: 
indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [55,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
......
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/call.py", line 44, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 580, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 989, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 1033, in _run_stage
    self._run_sanity_check()
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 1062, in _run_sanity_check
    val_loop.run()
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/utilities.py", line 182, in _decorator
    return loop_run(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/evaluation_loop.py", line 134, in run
    self._evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx, dataloader_iter)
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/evaluation_loop.py", line 391, in _evaluation_step
    output = call._call_strategy_hook(trainer, hook_name, *step_args)
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/call.py", line 309, in _call_strategy_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xc/.conda/envs/molbart_new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/strategies/strategy.py", line 403, in validation_step
    return self.lightning_module.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xc/xc_mol_seq/xc_work/seq_template/modules/model.py", line 1027, in validation_step
    bs, logits, loss = self.forward(batch)
  File "/home/xc/xc_mol_seq/xc_work/seq_template/modules/model.py", line 934, in forward
    indices, templates_candidates, templates_candidates_score = self.topk_candidates(
  File "/home/xc/xc_mol_seq/xc_work/seq_template/modules/model.py", line 1138, in topk_candidates
    scores, indices = scores.cpu().detach().numpy(), indices.cpu().detach().numpy()
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your pasted trace I see:

> indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [55,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.

That's a shape error. You're indexing into a tensor with an index larger than the tensor on the given dimension, similar to an "IndexOutOfBoundsException." It has nothing to do with moving tensors between cuda/cpu.

The stack trace points you to another part of the code, but that's because, as it says in the error:

> CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.